# While Loop inside Foreach PHP and pulls only one row?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I am having issue trying to pull orders that are assigned to driver - I have a foreach that lists all driver name that is working on that day, then in the while loop I fetch the driver's assigned orders and list them in their boxes but it only fetches the first driver and doesnt do the rest.

what am I doing wrong?

```
<?
// pull drivers according to the time right now
$driverlist = current_working_employees('',$slot,'driver');
$dlist = explode(',',$driverlist);
$row_i=0;$o='';
foreach($dlist as $driver){
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><b><? echo $driver; ?></b>
      <div ui-jq="nestable" class="dd">
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <?
            plugin(); 
            $q = "
            SELECT  p.ID,
                pm1.meta_value AS jckwds_timeslot,
                pm2.meta_value AS jckwds_date
            FROM  posts p LEFT JOIN postmeta pm1 
            ON (
                pm1.post_id=p.ID  
                AND
                pm1.meta_key='jckwds_timeslot'
            ) LEFT JOIN postmeta pm2 
            ON (
                pm2.post_id=p.ID  
                AND
                pm2.meta_key='jckwds_date'
            )
            WHERE   post_status='wc-processing' AND post_type='shop_order'";
            $r = mysql_query($q) or die("QUERY ERROR: ".mysql_error());
            while($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
                $oid = $rowa['ID'];
                if($rowa['jckwds_date'] == the_time_rightnow() && $rowa['jckwds_timeslot'] == $requested_time){

                    if( $driver == customer_detail($oid,'_wc_acof_4') ){
                        $o .= '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$oid.'">';
                        $o .= '<div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>';
                        $o .= '<div class="dd3-content">';
                        $o .= '#'.$oid.' '.customer_detail($oid,'_billing_first_name').' '.customer_detail($oid,'_billing_last_name').'<br />';
                        $o .= customer_detail($oid,'_shipping_address_1').'<br />';
                        $o .= 'Assigned to: '.customer_detail($oid,'_wc_acof_4').'<br />';
                        $o .= ' </div></li>';
                        $row_i++;

                    }
                }
            }
            echo ($row_i > 0) ? $o : '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="0"></li>';
            ?>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: How many rows that query return when you run it manually?

Comment: Instead of looping over all orders, it would be better if you could write the query so it only fetched the orders associated with the current driver.

Comment: You need to reset `$o` and `$row_i` each time through the `foreach` loop. Otherwise, it will include all the previous drivers' orders in the next driver.